# Converting an SurfaceTexture to a byte array in Android

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm trying to get a preview image as a raw byte array from the camera. Once I tried to use `onPreviewFrame ()` callback, but it turned out that it does not work properly, I don't know why. Now I'm trying to use the SurfaceTexture instance attached to the camera, but I found out that there is no API to get the byte buffer of the given SurfaceTexture.

Is there any way to 'extract' a byte array from a SurfaceTexture? Any comments with, if possible, a small example code will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no software-accessible byte array for a SurfaceTexture. The data is a GLES "external" texture, which you can access by rendering it to a framebuffer and reading the bytes out. Which is great if you want RGB, not so great if you want YUV. Assuming you're interested in YUV, you're probably better off figuring out why your camera callback isn't working.

Comment: Thank you for the advice :)